# Run vlookup/join for each list elements between different pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, csv, join, merge

I want to do vlookup between col1 in DF1 and col2 in DF2 and take col3 value, in my current code I’ve tried to break the list but the output no longer become a lists. Thanks

```
# Sample of data
df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[ ['A1','A2'], ['A1','A2','A3'], ['A4','A5'], ['A2','A5'] ]})  
df2=pd.DataFrame({'col2':['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5'],'col3':[1,2,3,4,5]})

# My Code
df1.set_index('col1', inplace=True)
df1['col1'] = df2.groupby('col2').col3.apply(list)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df1
```

And the expected output will be like this

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({'col4': [ [1,2],[1,2,3],[4,5],[2,5] ]})
```

Appreciate for any help. Thanks

Comment: `df1.apply(pd.Series.explode)`. Note there needs to be equal numbers of elements in the lists. So 2nd row will break it since 2 bookId but 3 bookPrice.

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for the reply, actually number of elements in the list are same. Sorry there is a bit mistake on my sample of data. I'll edit so it'll be clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of data quality / interpretation challenges with your data

- each *bookId* does not have an unique price
- *bookDetails* has duplicates

Taking this into account data can be merged.

```
import json
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""bookId,bookPrice
"['A1', 'A2', 'A3']","[5, 7, 9]"  
"['A4', 'A5']","[2, 4, 10]"  
"['B1']","[25]"  """)).replace("'", "\"", regex=True)  # needed for json.loads() to work

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""bookId,bookColor,bookName
A1,red,book_red  
A1,red,book_red2  
A2,blue,book_blue  
A2,blue,book_blue2  
A3,pink,book_pink  
A4,yellow,book_yellow  
A5,brown,book_brown  
A5,brown,book_brown2  
B1,green,book_green  
B1,green,book_green2  """))

# change from strings to actual lists
df1["bookId"] = df1["bookId"].apply(lambda s: json.loads(s))
df1["bookPrice"] = df1["bookPrice"].apply(lambda s: json.loads(s))
# expand bookId and join to first one in bookDetail
dfm = df1.explode("bookId").merge(df2.drop_duplicates("bookId", keep="first"), on="bookId", how="left")
```

### output

```
bookId  bookPrice bookColor      bookName
    A1  [5, 7, 9]       red    book_red  
    A2  [5, 7, 9]      blue   book_blue  
    A3  [5, 7, 9]      pink   book_pink  
    A4 [2, 4, 10]    yellow book_yellow  
    A5 [2, 4, 10]     brown  book_brown  
    B1       [25]     green  book_green
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the input. Actually there is a bit mistake with my sample of data. Number of bookPrice elements should be same with bookColor and bookName. Basically my requirement is only to do vlookup from DF1 and DF2 with boodID and take value of bookColor and bookName. And your code looks works for me, thanks again for ur help